# After I use pipe in C, if I redirect the stdout to a file, the file contains garbled characters

Tags: c, unix, pipe

I am new to use pipe in C code, so I have some confusing situation need your help,

I need to use `opt -print-callgraph foo.bc` to output the function call graph.

By default, the call graph will be in `stderr` and I can use `opt -print-callgraph foo.bc 2>call_graph.txt` to redirect stderr to file.

I need use a c program, give `foo.bc` as argument and generate the `call_graph.txt`

Suppose the compiled binary file is named `prog`, after I run `./prog foo.bc` I can get the call_graph.txt correctly.

But my problem is if I redirect the stdout of `prog` to a file, 
that is `prog foo.bc > output.txt`, the output.txt contains a lot of garbled characters. The output.txt maybe is a binary file.

I don't know what pipe does in the code, or where should I clean the stdout.

here is my code:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){   

    /* pipe to connect opt's stderr and our stdin */
    int pipe_callgraph[2];

    /* pid of opt */
    int opt_pid;
    char *bc_file;

    /* create pipe and check if pipe succeeded */
    if (pipe(pipe_callgraph) < 0) {
        perror("pipe");
        return 1;
    }

    /* create child process */
    opt_pid = fork();
    if (!opt_pid) { /* child process, to spawn opt */

        /* close the read end, since opt only write */
        close(pipe_callgraph[PIPE_READ]);

        /* bind pipe to stderr, and check */
        if (dup2(pipe_callgraph[PIPE_WRITE], STDERR_FILENO) < 0) {
            perror("dup2 pipe_callgraph");
            return 1;
        }

        /* print something to stderr */
        fprintf(stderr, "This is child, just before spawning opt with %s.\n", bc_file);

        /* spawn opt */
        if (execl("/usr/local/bin/opt", "opt", "-print-callgraph", bc_file, (char *)NULL) < 0) {
            perror("execl opt");
            return 1;
        }

        /* unreachable code */
        return 0;
    }

    /* parent process */

    /* close the write end, since we only read */
    close(pipe_callgraph[PIPE_WRITE]);

    /* since we don't need stdin, we simply replace stdin with the pipe */
    if (dup2(pipe_callgraph[PIPE_READ], STDIN_FILENO) < 0) {
        perror("dup2 pipe_callgraph");
        return 1;
    }

    FILE *fp = fopen("call_graph.txt", "w");
    char c = '\0';
    while (scanf("%c", &c) >= 1) {
        fprintf(fp, "%c", c);
    }
    fclose(fp);
```

And the output.txt like this:

[image]

==============edit===============

If I change these code

```
FILE *fp = fopen("call_graph.txt", "w");
char c = '\0';
while (scanf("%c", &c) >= 1) {
    fprintf(fp, "%c", c);
}
fclose(fp);
```

to

```
FILE *fp = fopen("call_graph.txt", "w");
fclose(fp);
```

The output.txt still contains garbled characters

and if I comment out these two lines, no garbled characters.

and also if change like this:

```
fflush(stdout);
FILE *fp = fopen("call_graph.txt", "w");
fclose(fp);
```

No garbled characters.

So I flush stdout so many times in this way:

```
fflush(stdout);
FILE *fp = fopen("call_graph.txt", "w");
char c = getchar();
while (c >= 1) {
    fflush(stdout);
    fprintf(fp, "%c", c);
    fflush(stdout);
    c = getchar();
}
fflush(stdout);
fclose(fp);
```

Still have garbled characters in output.txt

Comment: 1. Don't use `return` under `fork` if something fails in creation and executing; only `_exit()` is proper there. 2. The conventional exit code for exec error in child is `127`, not `1`. 3. `scanf("%c")` is too heavy and dangerous here. `getchar` is good alternative. Please fix all this and check results.

Comment: I've changed what you mentioned, still bad result. I notice that if I comment out `FILE *fp = fopen("output.txt", "w");` and `fclose(fp);`, and add some `printf("test out")`, no garbled characters in output.txt.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem, that is because `opt -print-callgraph foo.bc` prints the call graph to stderr and the content of the foo.bc to stdout, so I need use `>/dev/null` to capture the stdout.

The garbled characters have nothing to do with pipe.